# x intercepts and y intercepts

Tags: coordinate-systems

What can we say of y-intercept of a vertical line and x-intercept of a horizontal line?

Y-intercept of a line is y-coordinate of the point when line intersects y-axis. A vertical line other than y-axis would never intercept y-axis, so can we say it's intercept as infinity or it's better to regard it as undefined?

Comment: If your idea of the intercept on the vertical axis is the $c$ in $y=mx+c$ then there is nothing corresponding to $c$ in the vertical line where $x=k$

Comment: A set can be empty. Given a set of points, the set of $y$-intercepts is the set of all points with $x = 0$. If you have a vertical line $x = a$, and $a \neq 0$, then the set of all points on that line with $x = 0$ is empty, and so that line has no $y$-intercepts. If $a = 0$, then the set of all points on that line with $x = 0$, i.e., the set of $y$-intercepts, is $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Infinite number of y-intercept for y axis,perfect